# connecting to sql server with FluentNhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm using fluent nhibernate as ORM , I got the latest version by nuget where my sql server is 2012 , is it possible !? it doesn't offer me 2012 when I want to config

```
MsSqlConfiguration
    .MsSql2008
     .ShowSql()
```

whatever ! Now I have got the latest version by when run my my application and request to create data base in my sql server ,this error appear :

> Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

and just before this error , I had another trouble with login to sql server where I haven't set any username and password to my sql management studio !
what is the problem ?please

Answer (score 1):

MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008 should be compatible with MsSql2012. If there are really features/functions in 2012 you need, they can be added by inheriting from MsSql2008Dialect and adding them there.

> Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000

this indicates that you use FLuentNHibernate built against NH 3.3.1 but use NH other than 3.3.1. Decide for one Version or add a AssemblyBinding redirect in your `app.config`